# Choosing 13 cards from 52 such that all 4 aces are present.

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can a person be dealt 13 cards from a regular deck and receive all four aces and nine other cards?

My attempts to solve this using factorials has gotten me in a complete mess. Help is much appreciated

Comment: ${48\choose 9}$

Answer (score 3):

Does order matter?  If not, you just need to select $9$ cards from the remaining $48$

Comment: I see, many thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each card is uniquely identifiable by **both** number and shape:

$$\binom{52-4}{13-4}=1677106640$$